Pac4j redirect to white page after a while
I´m using Keycloak, Pac4j and Shiro...
I have no idea, but I´m getting after a while a white page and redirect to:
http://localhost:8080/oauth/callback?client_name=KeycloakOidcClient&session_state=ec6f1a5c-a992-4f66-8d7e-277d05e6cc1a&iss=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9009%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Fgixx&code=2e14eabd-7e63-4400-a340-b6062690d97c.ec6f1a5c-a992-4f66-8d7e-277d05e6cc1a.db37becc-2ebe-4d5c-9b28-238e59ba9b73
Token Tab:



It´s currently a showstopper for my project.
Here my shiro.ini:
[main]
#### Session
sessionIdCookie=org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.SimpleCookie
sessionIdCookie.path = /
sessionIdCookie.httpOnly = true
sessionIdCookie.name = sid
sessionIdCookie.domain = localhost
sessionIdCookie.maxAge=36000000
sessionIdCookie.secure = true
sessionIdCookie.sameSite = LAX

sessionManager =org.apache.shiro.web.session.mgt.DefaultWebSessionManager
sessionManager.sessionIdCookie =$sessionIdCookie
sessionManager.sessionIdCookieEnabled =true
securityManager.sessionManager= $sessionManager

# 3,600,000 milliseconds = 1 hour -> set to 10 hours
sessionManager.globalSessionTimeout= 36000000



#Keycloack
oidcConfig = org.pac4j.oidc.config.KeycloakOidcConfiguration
oidcConfig.realm = gixx
oidcConfig.baseUri = http://localhost:9009/auth
oidcConfig.discoveryURI = http://localhost:9009/auth/realms/myapp/.well-known/openid-configuration
oidcConfig.clientId = myapp-frontend
oidcConfig.secret = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
oidcConfig.clientAuthenticationMethodAsString = client_secret_basic
oidcConfig.useNonce = false
oidcConfig.scope = openid
oidcConfig.responseType = code
oidcConfig.withState = false
oidcConfig.disablePkce = true

keycloakOidClient = org.pac4j.oidc.client.KeycloakOidcClient
keycloakOidClient.name = KeycloakOidcClient
keycloakOidClient.configuration = $oidcConfig


roleAdminAuthGenerator = de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.shiropac4j.Pac4jRoleAdminAuthGenerator
keycloakOidClient.authorizationGenerator = $roleAdminAuthGenerator

clients = org.pac4j.core.client.Clients
clients.callbackUrl = http://localhost:8080/oauth/callback
clients.clients = $keycloakOidClient

pac4jRealm = io.buji.pac4j.realm.Pac4jRealm
pac4jRealm.principalNameAttribute = preferred_username

pac4jSubjectFactory = io.buji.pac4j.subject.Pac4jSubjectFactory
securityManager.subjectFactory = $pac4jSubjectFactory

config = org.pac4j.core.config.Config
config.clients = $clients


oidcSecurityFilter = org.pac4j.jee.filter.SecurityFilter
oidcSecurityFilter.config = $config
oidcSecurityFilter.clients = KeycloakOidcClient

customAuthorizer = de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.shiropac4j.Pac4jCustomAuthorizer
config.authorizers = authorizerCustom:$customAuthorizer

oidcSecurityFilter.authorizers = authorizerCustom

### Callback Filters
callbackFilter = org.pac4j.jee.filter.CallbackFilter
callbackFilter.config = $config

customCallbackLogic = de.dpunkt.myaktion.util.shiropac4j.Pac4jForceDefaultURLCallbackLogic
callbackFilter.callbackLogic = $customCallbackLogic

ajaxRequestResolver = org.pac4j.core.http.ajax.DefaultAjaxRequestResolver
ajaxRequestResolver.addRedirectionUrlAsHeader = true
keycloakOidClient.ajaxRequestResolver = $ajaxRequestResolver

logoutFilter = org.pac4j.jee.filter.LogoutFilter
logoutFilter.config = $config
logoutFilter.localLogout = true
logoutFilter.centralLogout = true
logoutFilter.destroySession = true


# AuthStrategy
#authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
authcStrategy = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.AtLeastOneSuccessfulStrategy

authenticator = org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.ModularRealmAuthenticator
securityManager.authenticator = $authenticator
securityManager.authenticator.authenticationStrategy = $authcStrategy
securityManager.realms = $pac4jRealm

# Caching
cacheManager = org.apache.shiro.cache.MemoryConstrainedCacheManager
securityManager.cacheManager = $cacheManager

# Using default form based security filter org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc = org.apache.shiro.web.filter.authc.FormAuthenticationFilter
authc.loginUrl = /common/login.jsf

anyofpermission = com.myapp.util.shiropac4j.CustomPermissionsAuthorizationFilter

# Protected URLs
[urls]

## PAC4J Filter
/oauth/callback = callbackFilter
/oauth/logout = logoutFilter

Stacktrace:
21:11:28,820 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-1) UT005023: Exception handling request to /oauth/callback: jakarta.servlet.ServletException: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Code not valid
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.cleanup(AdviceFilter.java:196)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:148)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.executeChain(AbstractShiroFilter.java:458)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter$1.call(AbstractShiroFilter.java:373)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.doCall(SubjectCallable.java:90)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.SubjectCallable.call(SubjectCallable.java:83)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.execute(DelegatingSubject.java:387)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AbstractShiroFilter.doFilterInternal(AbstractShiroFilter.java:370)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:154)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.3.Final//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:44)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@31.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1413)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.10.Final//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.12.Final//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Code not valid
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.executeTokenRequest(OidcAuthenticator.java:206)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.oidc.credentials.authenticator.OidcAuthenticator.validate(OidcAuthenticator.java:165)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.lambda$retrieveCredentials$0(BaseClient.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:183)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.core.client.BaseClient.retrieveCredentials(BaseClient.java:72)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.core.client.IndirectClient.getCredentials(IndirectClient.java:145)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.core.engine.DefaultCallbackLogic.perform(DefaultCallbackLogic.java:75)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.jee.filter.CallbackFilter.internalFilter(CallbackFilter.java:71)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.pac4j.jee.config.AbstractConfigFilter.doFilter(AbstractConfigFilter.java:72)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.ProxiedFilterChain.doFilter(ProxiedFilterChain.java:66)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.executeChain(AdviceFilter.java:108)
    at deployment.myapp.war//org.apache.shiro.web.servlet.AdviceFilter.doFilterInternal(AdviceFilter.java:137)
    ... 54 more

Settings in Keycloak:



Any idea?

On the client side, you get the following error: "Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Code not valid". It looks like this is the error returned by Keycloak: do you see more in the Keycloak logs? Is this code used twice or more? Does the code validation take too much time?

thanks for your feedback. No, in the Keycloak logs are no issues / errors.
I´ve updated the question with some more screenshots from the "Tokens" Tab from Keycloak. Do I need to change something here? Maybe increate the "OAuth 2.0 Device Code Lifespan" also to 10 hours? Or maybe the "Access Token Lifespan" ?

The code should have a short lifetime (30 seconds for example) while an access token lasts more (15 minutes or 2 hours). I don't think your problem is related to access tokens: it seems your code is not recognized: "Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Code not valid". I'm surprised there is not more logs on Keycloak about this issue.

I´m stil not sure... It´s happening like this: I´m on a page and idle for some time(e.g. 1 hour)... Now I change e.g. a primefaces tab and I´m redirected to a white page with this URL: http://localhost:8080/oauth/callback?client_name=KeycloakOidcClient&session_state=284ebe26-dff5-465b-8d8a-253bf5a352fd&iss=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9009%2Fauth%2Frealms%2Fmyapp&code=123456789 ... If I try to refresh the page I got this error message: Caused by: org.pac4j.core.exception.TechnicalException: Bad token response, error=invalid_grant, description=Code not valid
How can this be fixed?

I´m also not able to see any error messages before I enter after the redirect to the white page... during redirect to the white page I cannot see any error logs

any idea? it seems the session from keycloak expired and than I got a white page...
